# Auto-parsing of a complicated json structure

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a home assignment on my course to parse new in json format. The data structure of json-file is strict but too much complicated.E. g. I need this string to get a meaningful entry for me:

```
json_parsed ['rss']['channel']['item'][0]['description']['__cdata']
```

(more than 40 such entries)
So I could analyse the structure manually and get the job done afterwards. But I learn to automate a stuff like this, so I'd like to know, can the json structure be parsed automatically? In what way if yes? I have no idea yet...

Comment: I'm not sure really what you're asking... python does have a [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) stdlib package, but it seems you've already read in the file into a python object given that you're using slice notation in your example

Comment: I decoded this structure manually. Can it be done using json module? I can't figure out how...

Comment: given a json `["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]` as *data.json*, load it into python with `data = json.load(jsonfile)` where `jsonfile = open('data.json', 'r')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you parse a json string with the json module, the result behaves a dictionary with nested dictionaries and lists. You could definitely traverse the structure automatically with something like this (using the json given by @Aaron):

```
>>> def explore(json):
...  if isinstance(json,dict):
...   for k,v in json.items():
...    print(str(k)+':')
...    explore(v)
...  elif isinstance(json,list):
...   for i in json:
...    explore(i)
...  else:
...   print(json)
...
>>> explore(json.loads(string))
foo
bar:
baz
None
1.0
2
None
```